# Python JoinableQueue and Queue Thread Not Completing

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using the following code to complete a task using multithreading with Queue and Joinable Queue. Sometimes the script executes perfectly other times it stalls at the end of the task without ending the worker and will not continue on to the next portion of the script. I am new to working with Queue and JoinableQueue and I need to find out why this stalling happens.

Before this part in the code I run another Queue, JoinableQueue worker to download some data and it works perfectly fine everytime. Do I need to close() any thing from the first Queue/JoinableQueue?  Is there a way to check if it stalls and if so continue on?

Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue
from threading import Thread

def run_this_definition(hr):
    #do things here
    return()

def worker():
while True:
    item = jq.get()
    run_this_definition(item)
   jq.task_done()
return()

q = Queue()
jq = JoinableQueue()

number_of_threads = 8

for i in range(number_of_threads):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start() 

input_list = [0,1,2,3,4]
for item in input_list:
    jq.put(item)
jq.join()
print "finished"
```

The script never prints "finished" when it stalls, but seems to finish all the tasks and stalls at the end of the 'run_this_definition' on the very last item in the Queue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python threads and queue example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173975/python-threads-and-queue-example)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using the `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()`!? Use the `Queue.Queue()` instead for threading. It has a `.join()` and a `.task_done()` [method as well](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.task_done). Furthermore you should pass your queue as an argument to your threads: See the following example:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

def worker(jq):
    while True:
        item = jq.get()
        # Do whatever you have to do.
        print '{}: {}'.format(threading.currentThread().name, item)
        jq.task_done()
    return()

number_of_threads = 4
input_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
jq = Queue()
for i in range(number_of_threads):
    t = Thread(target=worker, args=(jq,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
for item in input_list:
    jq.put(item)
jq.join()

print "finished"
```

The print output form multiple threads might look messy, but as an example it should be fine.

For the future: Please provide a comprehensive example of your code. Neither your imports, nor `number_of_threads`, `run_this_definition` or `input_list` were defined in your example.

Comment: Great I will try this and add the appropriate portion of my code above.  Thank you.

Comment: Doing this gives me the error worker takes 0 arguments 1 given - should I remove the args=(jq,) portion?

Comment: @AshleyA. whoops. no you should allow your worker to take an argument:) I fixed the code.

Comment: No problem - thank you! I tried this and is still is stalling again after completing the last item in the input list. Could it be that one of the threads is stalling somewhere along the way? Would there be a way to check to see what threads are currently running?

Comment: @AshleyA hmm then its getting hard to help, without knowing more about your code. You can use `threading.enumerate()` to get a list of threads that are alive. General advise: try to isolate your problem. Use my example (I guess it is working for you?!) and add your code step by step until it starts stalling. Furthermore use `print` or even better the logging module to debug.